# Using OR-Tools with .NET and GUROBI

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, or-tools, c#

We want to model our MILP problem with Google OR-Tools in .NET, and solve it using GUROBI (solver may change in the next 1-2 years). However, we couldn't find the correct syntax to call GUROBI.

https://developers.google.com/optimization says it is `Solver solver = Solver.CreateSolver(solver_id);`. There are examples of calling GLOP and SCIP, but not for GUROBI (or we failed to find). What we tried listed below, but `solver` returns `null`.

`using Google.OrTools.LinearSolver;`

`Solver solver = Solver.CreateSolver("GUROBI");`

`Solver solver = Solver.CreateSolver("GUROBI_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING");`

Question 1: What is the correct way of calling GUROBI?

Question 2: Does OR-Tools allow using callbacks of GUROBI? If so, any source suggestions to refer? https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/cb_codes.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. the library needs to find the gurobi shared library before you can create the solver. You can set GUROBI_HOME to help.
2. you can have callbacks, but only in c++. Look for or-tools/linear_solver/linear_solver.h. Search for callbacks.